# Track which country user had, when they downloaded the app from Google Play

Tags: android, location, google-play, google-play-services

My app should be available for UK users (but only on UK territory) and be available to France(FR) user, but only on FR territory. So if a UK user visits France, the application should not work.

How could I track which country user had (from Google play point of view), when the user downloaded the app?

(But it should be based on google play information, and not on geo-location or network location)